# Could not resolve com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Getting these errors when trying to run Android Java project
 `Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0.`
`Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.`

`Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/smarteist/autoimageslider/1.4.0/autoimageslider-1.4.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized`

[image]

`implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0'`

i tried toggle offline mode

i tried invalidate caches
i tried deleting `.gradle` caches
i tried updating android studio, gradle version
i tried a VPN, switching network
i tried Gradle Jdk 19, 1.8, 11
i tried adding `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` and `jcenter()`
i need help working this out

Comment: AFAIK, that library's basically abandoned and isn't directly published anywhere anymore, so you'll have to go through JitPack. Keep the `maven { … }` entry, and then make sure you have the current, correct dependency, as shown on [the relevant page on their site](https://jitpack.io/#smarteist/Android-Image-Slider/1.4.0).

Comment: Can you please attach the project level build.gradle and setting.gradle  screenshot if possible??

Comment: `buildscript {
...
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.jfrog.org/libs-snapshot" }
    }
}`

Comment: settings.gradle 

`include ':app'
rootProject.name = "Ngo"
`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 0):

since **jcenter** has been ***shutdown***, officially they provided solution for this in their **github** based on new structure of Updated Android Studio versions.

simple, put following line in **settings.gradle** file-

```
maven {
url "https://jcenter.bintray.com"
}
```

find more at [**Github | smarteist/Android-Image-Slider**](https://github.com/smarteist/Android-Image-Slider/issues/251)

please mark this one is as answer if it is helpful so others can do same. thank you.